# How do I configure CUPS and change SAMBA setting for no printers?

Tags: 12.04, printing, samba, mythbuntu, syslog

A couple of time an hour, these lines show up in `syslog`

```
Feb 19 09:20:11 KISE-055 smbd[5685]: [2013/02/19 09:20:11.609603,  0] printing/print_cups.c:110(cups_connect)
Feb 19 09:20:11 KISE-055 smbd[5685]:   Unable to connect to CUPS server localhost:631 - Connection refused
Feb 19 09:20:11 KISE-055 smbd[1081]: [2013/02/19 09:20:11.610113,  0] printing/print_cups.c:487(cups_async_callback)
Feb 19 09:20:11 KISE-055 smbd[1081]:   failed to retrieve printer list: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
```

Now this computer is the client and server for Mythtv (Mythbuntu),  There are no printers attached, nor does any use of the HTPC require a printer.  I do use occasionally print to PDF.

What do I need to do to stop samba from performing this query and producing these messages in `syslog` ?

Answer (score 8):

If you are a home user and using samba purely for file sharing from a server or NAS you’re probably not interested in sharing printers through it. If so, you can prevent this error from occurring by adding the following lines to your `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
printing = bsd
printcap name = /dev/null
```

Restart samba:

```
/etc/init.d/smbd restart
```

…check your logs:

```
less /var/log/samba/log.smbd
```

and the error should now no longer be appearing.

Comment: Cool, and not in the Eskimo way...

Comment: Setting `printcap name = /dev/null` was enough for me, although I'm using Fedora 19 (samba-4.0.9-3.fc19.x86_64).

Answer (score 1):

Well 1st and unexpected is that Mythbuntu does not install CUPS by default, so the soultion was simple, install CUPS from Ubuntu software.  `smbd` can now connect to CUPS, although no printers are used.

CUPS can be maintained by using http:`//localhost:631/` in a browser, not mention in info on Ubuntu software